# Split NSString in exactly two pieces

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Which is the optimum way to split an NSString in two pieces? My idea was to split a filename in two parts the filename itself and the extension. I would like to know which could be the most simple one.

Comment: Note it is always worth trying to do something like that yourself for example by reading documentation, before posting a question here. Especially when you can show some code you have tried. Otherwise you will easily get down votes. or posts deleted. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

`NSString`offers some of its own implementations that will do exactly what you want for filenames and paths.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW38 and there for example `lastPathComponent`or `pathExtension`.

`[yourFilePath lastPathComponent]` gives you the filename of a given path. `[yourFilePath pathExtension]` gives you the extension. Note this works for `NSURL` as well, but expects a valid path or URL respectively.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *filename = [sFilename lastPathComponent]; // this will give you pure filename if it's a path already
NSArray *filenameParts = [filename componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if ([filenameParts count] == 2) {
    NSString *file = [filenameParts objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileExtension = [filenameParts objectAtIndex:1];
    ...
}
```